# Los datos de Excel se copian mal, uno se pone bien y los demás mal

Tags: excel, vba

He hecho la parte principal del macro, pero a la hora de mandar a copiar la información se salta una columna; hasta donde sé el código debería estar bien. Una disculpa, soy nuevo con esto de los macros.

```
''' Sub insertar_registro()

Sheets("GENERAL").Select

' Ultima fila editada ultimo = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Si el ultimo registro es del departamento JURIDICO If Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Value = "JURIDICO" Then
    For i = 1 To 10
            ' Se copia el utimo campo utilizado
            Cells(ultimo, i).Copy
            
            ' Se selecciona la hoja JURIDICO
            Sheets("JURIDICO").Select
            
            ' Siguiente fila a editar
            siguienteFila = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            
            ' Seleccion de la celda a editar
            Cells(siguienteFila, i).Select
            
            ' Se pega la informacion de la celda en la hoja activa
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            ' Se regresa a la hoja GENERAL
            Sheets("GENERAL").Select
    Next i End If End Sub '''
```

A la hora de ejecutar me sale así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes metido dentro de tu bucle `siguienteFila = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1` y por eso sucede lo que sucede.

Cuando `i=1` entonces la variable `siguienteFila` se calcula bien (por ejemplo pongamos que vale 10). Pega el dato en la celda A10 y sigue.

Pero entonces cuando `i=2` vuelves a recalcular `siguienteFila` y claro, la última ahora es la 10 en la columna 1, así que se incrementa a 11.

Saca del bucle `siguienteFila = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1` y lo pruebas

Y por cierto, la versión corta de tu código, ya que siempre pegas las columnas 1 a 10, sería:

```
Dim UltimaGeneral As Long
Dim UltimaJuridico As Long

With ThisWorkbook
    UltimaGeneral = .Worksheets("GENERAL").Range("A" & .Worksheets("GENERAL").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    UltimaJuridico = .Worksheets("JURIDICO").Range("A" & .Worksheets("JURIDICO").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If .Worksheets("GENERAL").Range("K" & UltimaGeneral).Value = "JURIDICO" Then
        .Worksheets("GENERAL").Range("A" & UltimaGeneral & ":J" & UltimaGeneral).Copy .Worksheets("JURIDICO").Range("A" & UltimaJuridico + 1 & ":J" & UltimaJuridico + 1)
    End If
End With
```